# Launching a sudo gui from desktop

Tags: bash, java, gui

Environment: CentOS 5.10 on 32 Bit.

`test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /dump
sudo /opt/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java -jar mytest.jar
```

`mytest.jar` will pop a GUI app in the desktop, username is in sudoers with NOPASSWD.

Created a launcher in desktop, on double click it doesn't launch the GUI.

If I run `test.sh` in terminal, it works without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to R click on your script, go to Permissions and then mark the checkbox "Allow executing file as a program".

Comment: Yes, i already tried this, but no luck